# Transmission makes more noise than normal in passing gear

Tags: noise, transmission, acura, mdx

My 2003 Acura MDX seems to make more noise when it switches to passing gear than it used to. It can even get to almost a screech, albeit a low volume screech.

Although maybe not related, I recently got the oil changed. Afterwards I happened to be looking under the car and just aft of the oil pan it looked like a case of some kind (a transfer case?) was lightly coated with oil. No oil makes it to the ground. Could it be leaking gear oil? Can I check that oil level?

Comment: Could be many things.  First, I would want to identify the oil on the transfer case.  There is usually a vent on top of the case that could be spewing oil, or it could be leaking from a seal.  Gear oil has a bad smell.  you should be able to tell if it's leaking gear oil.    There should be a drain on the bottom and a fill plug on the side.  Open the fill and stick your little finger inside.  If you can't touch any oil, it's low.   Have you ever changed the transfer case oil?  How many miles on the car?

Comment: I went to check the oil on the outside of the transfer case and it's gone. I had to drive 200 miles through the rain to visit a relative on Sunday and that washed it away. It's Thursday now and there's no sign of any oil so I don't know why there was some before. I'm still at my relative's house and don't have my tools with me so I can't check the level of the oil. The Acura MDX has 160,000 miles but has been serviced regularly by my mechanic. I think he changed the oil in the transfer case and differentials regularly.